# running pyinstaller on boot

Tags: python, windows, macos, startup, pyinstaller

i want to make a application with pyinstaller that run on mac and windows os...
if it was something like check my(s) online site(s) and see if it's on, i want it to auto-run always i start my pc and on background while is on and i'm using it
if it goes down a alarm sound start and  pop up a window (starting the gui app where you do stuff like add your sites, set alarm and etc...) saying the link and info, the whole concept isn't (personal use + upload opensource),

My problem is, how i make it run on boot after the installation without needing to do anything else,

in one line:
how i startup a program on boot(enable it through installation), in windows/mac os?

Comment: Windows: http://superuser.com/questions/63326/enable-exe-to-run-at-startup
OS X: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2602

Comment: it help on how to startup, but not how to configure the pyinstaller to do this, i will try figure it out by my self thanks, but any extra help will be useful

Comment: If your lucky it can be configured with commanline options, then just add them to the startup. If it has a gui where you must click, there are platformspecific ways to get a handle to a gui element like a button and use it from another process (eg. win via python: http://www.getautoma.com/), or to use a combination of hotkeys triggered from for example a pythonscript/applescript.